# better piechart color scheme

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart

I am trying to create a pie chart, as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# make a square figure and axes
plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,10))
plt.axes([0.01, 0.1, 0.6, 0.6])
# plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

# The slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise.
labels = 'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4'
fracs = pd.Series([10,30, 50,10],index=labels) 
fracs.plot(kind='pie', labels=None, autopct='%1.0f%%')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.95, .9), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.,labels=labels)
plt.title('pie chart demo which should be center aligned not left', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})

plt.show()
```

Which is yeilding a piechart as:[image]
But, I am facing two problem:
1) I dont like the color scheme. I would like a color scheme more inline with [image](I need 12 colors)
2) Titel is centered at the pie chart only. The legend is somehow out. I am trying to get the title centered over the chart and the legend.

Can someone kindly help?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a ggplot colorscheme that you are trying to emulate.

And your `plt.axes` command is what is displacing your chart to the left.

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,10))

labels = 'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4'
sizes = [10,30, 50,10]
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]